# Consumir serviço de envio de arquivos

Tags: c#, asp.net

Eu tenho basicamente um serviço em c# que foi feito pra receber um arquivo, o que quero é usar esse serviço, criei uma pagina asp.net com um fileUpluod, e queria colocar pra o mesmo funcionar, como faço?

Classe de Serviço:

```
  public class UpluodService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod(Description = "Adiciona um arquivo")]
    public void AddArquivo(Autenticacao autenticacao,Arquivo arquivo)
    {
        Autenticar(autenticacao);
        ArquivoController.GetInstance().AddArquivo(arquivo);



    }

public class Autenticacao
{
    public string Usuario { get; set; }
    public string Senha { get; set; }
}
```

Classe de arquivo:

```
 public class Arquivo
{
    public Arquivo() 
    {
        ArquivoVersoes = new List<ArquivoVersao>();
    }
    public string ARQUIVO_GUID { get; set; }
    public string XARQUIVO { get; set; }
    public string TAG { get; set; }
    public string EXTENSAO { get; set; }
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public bool IS_STREAM { get; set; }
    public string ULT_ARQUIVO_VERSAO_GUID { get; set; }
    public string TIPO_DE_ARQUIVO_GUID { get; set; }
    public string DIRETORIO_GUID { get; set; }
    public TipoDeArquivo TipoDeArquivo { get; set; }
    public List<ArquivoVersao> ArquivoVersoes { get; set; } 
}
```

o que eu fiz foi tentar pelo evento do botao enviar, passar o arquivo vejam:

```
 protected void btnUpluod_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
           UpluodService teste = new UpluodService();
            Autenticacao autenticacao = new Autenticacao();
            Arquivo arq = new Arquivo();
            autenticacao.Usuario = "joao";
            autenticacao.Senha = "123456";
            fileUpluod.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Files") + "//" + fileUpluod.FileName);
            arq.XARQUIVO = fileUpluod.FileName;
            ged.AddArquivo(autenticacao, arq);
            Response.Write("Enviado com sucesso!!!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Não foi possivel enviar!!!");
            throw new GEDServiceException("Erro ao enviar arquivo");
        }
    }
```

Tentei dessa forma , mas ele sempre cai no catch, e não consigo identificar o erro, mas sei que deve estar errado essa implementação, quem puder ajudar agradeço.

Exception:

```
 System.Exception was unhandled by user code
 HResult=-2146233088
 Message=Erro ao adicionar arquivo
 Source=Cliente
 StackTrace:
   em Cliente._Default.buttonEnviar_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) na           em   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   em System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   em  System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   em System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
   em System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
   em System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

InnerException:

Comment: poderia colocar a Exception para que possamos analisar?

Comment: entra aqui por favor: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20863/discussion-between-war-lock-and-tobymosque

Comment: firewall não permite URLs com 'chat'.

Comment: coloquei a exception

Comment: Acredito que o erro esteja acontecendo dentro do webservice, possivelmente no método na chamada do método .AddArquivo(arquivo).
você consegue pegar a excessão real gerada no webservice?

Comment: System.NullReferenceException: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.

Comment: arquivo tem varios atributos, porem so setei uma, tem algo ave?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20873/discussion-between-war-lock-and-tobymosque).

Comment: só se você estiver acessando alguma propriedade ou método de TipoDeArquivo ou ArquivoVersoes.

Comment: entao o que pode ser?

Comment: Você está tendo alguma dificuldade para debuggar o webservice?

Comment: O webservice acho que está correto, foi outra pessoa que implementou,to fazendo apenas o cliente.

Comment: Então você terá de ver com esta pessoa.

Comment: VOce viu o erro que comentei?System.NullReferenceException: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto

Comment: Agora ta com esse erro: Erro ao adicionar arquivo:System.UnauthorizedAccessException: O acesso ao caminho 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Cliente\Cliente' foi negado.

Comment: Uma duvida, se eu to em outro projeto, e importo um serviço a senha de autenticação tem que ficar no web.config do cliente, ou do serviço?